# Typescript: why does 'this' keyword return 'Window'?

Tags: typescript

Why `this` keyword returns `Window` but no class items?

```
public setfunc() {
        setTimeout(function test() {
        console.log(this);
    }, 1000);
}
```

[Typescript playground example](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Playground#src=class%20A%20%7B%0A%09private%20obj1%3A%20any%3B%0A%09public%20obj2%3A%20any%3B%0A%09%0A%09constructor(bla1)%20%7B%0A%09%09this.obj1%20%3D%20this.obj2%20%3D%20bla1%3B%20%0A%09%7D%0A%09%0A%09public%20setfunc()%20%7B%0A%09%09setTimeout(function%20test()%20%7B%0A%09%09console.log(this)%3B%0A%09%7D%2C%201000)%3B%0A%09%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Avar%20test%20%3D%20new%20A('test')%3B%0Atest.setfunc()%3B)

Comment: There's no class in the code presented here...

Comment: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#why-does-this-get-orphaned-in-my-instance-methods

Comment: It seems there are not much documentation for this nuance. But i found duplicating doc in [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/'this'-in-TypeScript). And i did not found any question in stackoverflow for this topic. But nevertheless, thanks for answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As with JavaScript, `this` is highly contextual.

When you run a timer, there is no object or element to supply as the target of the event callback, so you get the global `window` scope.

You can use arrow functions to maintain the scope at the time you create the callback:

```
setTimeout(() => {
        console.log(this);
    }, 1000);
}
```

Or handle it manually...

```
var _x = this;
setTimeout(function test() {
        console.log(_x);
    }, 1000);
}
```